# CK II Sword of islam adds anything new to the non-muslim gameplay?

Tags: crusader-kings-2, sword-of-islam

Does Sword of Islam add more events or other things to the game if i play a non-muslim leader? It affects only the muslim rulers or the muslim world ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It expands the map to introduce more Muslim states in North Africa, although I'm unsure if you need the DLC for that. Paradox also vaguely promises "20 new features", but those might just be relevant to Muslim factions.

The biggest "change" that is relevant for a non-Muslim player, is likely that the AI Muslim leaders need to adhere to decadence. Due to this, their vast empires seem to crumble on a semi-regular basis.

If you don't plan on playing as a Muslim, then I don't think you're missing out on much (but please correct me if I'm wrong). However, the DLC is often on sale for next to nothing either by itself, or in a bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Sword of Islam DLC release features a few things other than Muslim themed content, cf: [SoI notes](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Sword_of_Islam)

Specifically

- > A map extension into Mali with some new counties and titles

For interest it was released along side [Patch 1.06](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Patch_1.06), the features of which are available to everyone, regardless of whether you own the DLC